# .lib file gives wrong method names C++

Tags: c++, dll, .lib

I'm using Embarcadero XE8 C++ builder 32 bit and I'm trying to convert a .dll file to a .lib. I did this with using the `implib`-tool. [more info here](http://shane.hydrus.net/documentation/tutorial/GeneratingBorlandCppLibraryFiles/index.html).

I've got my new .lib file now. And it isn't working so I used a `TDump`on the library. When I check out the Tdump, the names aren't correct.

Instead of having the name: `CEasyPLCHandler` it says `??0CEasyPLCHandler@@QAE@ABV0@@Z`.

It seems that every method in the library added the `??0` at the start and `@@QAE@ABV0@@Z`at the end. When I simply open the library and replace `??0`and `@@QAE@ABV0@@Z` with nothing it gives a new error:

.lib contains invalid OMF record, type 0x50

So I can't just simply change the text in the library.

How can I change the method names in my library? If that isn't possible how can I get my library working? I already made a topic about converting files: [Linker error “contains invalid OMF record” 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695738/linker-error-contains-invalid-omf-record-2/32695924?noredirect=1#comment53235736_32695924)

Comment: You might want to read about [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Also note that `implib` will not convert a .dll to a .lib. It will just make an import library so you can use the dll in your project.

Comment: @Wimmel So I also should include the .dll file or? how does that work?

Comment: You will need the .dll at runtime. But as you seem to have problems compiling, you have to fix that first.

Comment: @Wimmel well I get the errors of Unresolved external errors, so I need to get my library fixed first.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg When I check the DLL file it actually shows the same stuff as the .lib file. the `??0` and `@@QAE@ABV0@@Z` or some other code on the end is added to the methods.

Comment: You *did* read the article I linked to in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes I read it, it's about adding symbols to indentify what it is. And since my lib has more CEasyPLCHandler constructors it adds these symbols. But ye, the problem is just a visual basic .lib doesnt use the same symbols as a C++ builder .lib

Comment: So you want to use these symbols from an external application, like a Visual Basic program? Then you need to explore the `extern "C"` linkage specifier with causes symbols not to be mangled, or some other way to load and use the DLL with the mangled names.

Comment: Well simply, I'm trying to convert a visual basic .lib to a C++ builder lib. Some methods are correctly given but some aren't because of this problem. how does `the extern "C"` part works? I'm pretty new to C++ and Embarcadero.

Comment: _I'm trying to convert a visual basic .lib to a C++ builder lib._ - I think you need to ask visual basic experts what you need to do in visual basic to allow to use the .dll in c++. The answer might be that it is not possible, but I don't know. It might also depend on the visual basic version you are using. The main problem is that you need a header file to use the .lib you created. A better approach might be creating a COM object in visual basic, and use that in c++ builder. That will work, but you need knowledge of COM, both in visual basic as in c++.